# header overlapping content when page size changes HTML

Tags: html, css

Im having an issue where I want my header to be fixed to the top of the web browser, same with the nav bar i made. Problem is, when I change the size of the web browser, the header covers the content and moves the nav bar. How can I solve this?

```
<body>
    <h1>Knox Enterprises Inc.</h1>
    <div class="nav">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="About.html">About</a>
        <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>

    </div>
    <div class="adjust">
        <div class="home">
            <div class="home-pictures">
                <img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/14o91c1.jpg" width="300px" height="225px">
                <img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/2rpzh3p.jpg" width="300px" height="225px">
            </div>
            <div class="home-pictures2">
                <img src="http://i68.tinypic.com/rswqoy.jpg" width="300px" height="225px">
                <img src="http://i66.tinypic.com/2lm8bdg.jpg" width="300px" height="225px">
            </div>
            <div class="home-description">
                <ul>
                    <h5>Riveredge, NJ</h5>
                    <h5>Date Completed: June 2014</h5>
                </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="home">
            <div class="home-pictures">
                <img src="home_5.jpg" width="300px" height="225px">
                <img src="home_6.jpg" width="300px" height="225px">
            </div>
            <div class="home-pictures2">
                <img src="home_7.jpg" width="300px" height="225px">
                <img src="home_8.jpg" width="300px" height="225px">
            </div>
            <div class="home-description">
                <ul>
                    <h5>Teaneck, NJ</h5>
                    <h5>Date Completed: March 2015</h5>
                </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="home">
            <div class="home-pictures">
                <img src="home_9.jpg" width="300px" height="225px">
                <img src="home_10.jpg" width="300px" height="225px">
            </div>
            <div class="home-pictures2">
                <img src="home_11.jpg" width="300px" height="225px">
                <img src="home_12.jpg" width="300px" height="225px">
            </div>
            <div class="home-description">
                <ul>
                    <h5>Tenafly, NJ</h5>
                    <h5>Date Completed: August 2016</h5>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

and my .css code is

```
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-image:url("backround.jpg");
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
    }
    /*Knox Header*/
    h1 {
        position: fixed;
        top: -40px;
        width: 100%;
        font-family: Georgia;
        color: white;
        text-shadow: 4px 4px black;
        background-image: url("header.jpg");
        font-size: 60px;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        border-bottom: 5px solid orange;
        border-top: 5px solid orange;
    }
    /*Nav Menu/Home Page*/
    .nav {
        position:fixed;
        padding-top:78px;
        background-image:#606060;
        overflow: hidden;
        }
    .nav a {
        font-family: Helvetica;
        background-color:black;
        float: left;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 12px;
        border-right: 2px solid orange;
        border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
        border-top: 2px solid orange;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        }
    .nav a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: black;
        }
    .home {
        text-align:center;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        }
    .home-pictures, .home-pictures2{
        height:auto;
        width:auto;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    .home img {
        border: 1px solid white;
        }
    .home-description {
        line-height: 0px;
        color: white;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        font-family: Helvetica;
        font-size: 18px;
        }
```

Comment: give your content a margin-top equal or higher than your header height. having it change with media queries or on resize with js

Comment: here is fiddle with solution https://jsfiddle.net/stqo2mxk/ praticly Kirk Hadden solution implemented

Comment: haven't incorporated java into my html yet, but ill try this possibly. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put both elements inside a container and make this container fixed instead of using two elements with `position: fixed`.
They are both put out of flow and thus they will not be affected by each other (thus the navigation bar will be overlapped by the h1 when there is not enough width for the content so that it has to break the line)

https://jsfiddle.net/7ntdes6t/

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by wrapping your header and nav bar in it's own tag, like:

```
<header class='header-fixed'>
  <h1>Knox Enterprises Inc.</h1>
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="About.html">About</a>
    <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Then, you only have to worry about one fixed-position element.

From there, you have some options.

1. You could use javascript to watch for window resizes and adjust the margin-top on your  accordingly.
2. You could figure up exactly how tall your header is at common browser sizes, and use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) to adjust the rest.

Edit:

Actually, you know what would be easier?

```
<header>
  ...
</header>
<div id="Content">
  ...
</div> 

header { 
  height: 120px; 
} 
#content { 
  height: calc(100% - 120px); 
  overflow-y: scroll; 
}
```

If you can figure out exactly how tall your header is, then you could use calc() to set the height of the rest of your content, and actually make that div the part that scrolls. At that point, you don't need fixed positioning.

Comment: ok, I'm going to try and do some of these. Im kind of new to HTML so need to look into how to do media queries.

Comment: Actually, you know what would be easier?

    <header>
    </header>
    <div id="Content">
    </div>

    header { height: 120px; }
    #content { height: calc(100% - 120px); overflow-y: scroll; }

Comment: ill try and implement this.

Comment: hey, that seemed to solve the problem! Thanks @Kirk Hadden